# Sum of powers of $i$: $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} i^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I want to know if this series is convergent or divergent
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} i^n$$
where $i$ is the complex number.

I can't remember all the convergence tests I took in the university, but I searched the internet and I couldn't find anything about this.

For real numbers I think there is a test to see if this fraction $\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}$ is greater or less than $1$, does it work for complex numbers too?

And I know that, $i^n=1,i,-1,-i$ so the infinite sum is not infinity of course, so I guess it is convergent but there is still a chance that it does not exist.

Thank you for the help...

Comment: What is the most fundamental test for convergence/divergence? Does this series pass it?

Comment: Can you say something about $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|$? Do you know some relation between this limit an convergence/divergence of the series $\sum a_n$?

Comment: Is it too much effort to evaluate the first partial sums $1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,\cdots$ ?

Comment: For a series to converge the terms **must** approach zero in the limit. In this case that does not hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then you necessarily have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ and, consequently, also $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |a_n|=0$.

If you look at your series $a_n=i^n$, then you can see that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |a_n|=1$, since $|a_n|=1$ for each $n$. (We have $|a_n|=|i^n|=|i|^n=1^n=1$.) Therefore the series does not converge. (And it is not difficult to show also that the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$ does not exist - I chose the possibility with the absolute values simply because here we get constant sequence and we can immediately see the limit.)

I will also add that this is a special case of [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ converges if and only if $|x|<1$. (And this is true for complex numbers, too.)

You have also asked about [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test):

> For real numbers I think there is a test to see if this fraction $\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}$ is greater or less than $1$, does it work for complex numbers too?

Yes, the ratio test works also for series of complex numbers. Notice that in ratio test you are looking at $r=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\rvert$. (The absolute value is important here - you want to check whether $r<1$, this is meaningful only if $r$ is a real number.) But this criterion does not help here, since for this series the limit is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the sequence of partial sums. The sequence of partial sums is: $1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,\dots$. You see that the limit does not exist. So the series does not converge.

Answer (score 2):

For each $N\in\Bbb Z_+$,$$\sum_{n=0}^Ni^n=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }4\mid N\\1+i&\text{ if }4\mid N-1\\i&\text{ if }4\mid N-2\\0&\text{ if }4\mid N-3.\end{cases}$$Therefore, the sequence $\left(\sum_{n=0}^Ni^n\right)_{N\in\Bbb Z_+}$ diverges. In other words, your series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any convergence test: if it converged, the sequence of partial sums $\sum_{k=0}^N i^k$ would have a limit. Now
$$S_N=\left\{\begin{alignedat}{2}1&\quad \text{if } N\equiv 0\mod 4, &\quad 1+i &\quad\text{if } N\equiv 1\mod 4, \\ i &\quad \text{if } N\equiv 2\mod 4, & 0 &\quad \text{if } N\equiv 3\mod 4,
\end{alignedat}\right.$$
so we have a periodic sequence instead.

Answer (score 0):

:)

Suppose \begin{align*} c&=1+i+i^2+i^3+\cdots\cr
&=(1+i)-(1+i)+\cdots&=0\\
&=1+(i-1)-(i-1)+\cdots&=1\\
\therefore\quad  &0=1\end{align*}